# ASP.NET Core 3.1 responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="border">
        <img height="300" width="400" src="~/Images/vg.png" class="rounded"/>
        <p>Paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it responsive? Without width and heights it goes beyond the screen, with set height and width its no longer responsive.

Comment: You can try to specify height and width as percentage instead of pixels. Or you can set max-width and max-height of the image.

Comment: @Marmellad setting max height works like not having height and width set at all (image beyond screen).

Comment: Max height and max width are not html attributes, they are CSS properties. So it should work via CSS.

Comment: @Marmellad yeah just find out that i have to use style. I guess it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a specific value will cause the width and height, and it will not change due to the change of the window. You can set the percentage so that when you adjust the window, it will change according to the ratio of the window.

```
<img src="~/Images/vg.png" height="30%" width="40%" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `img-fluid` class to your image, which is provided by the **bootstrap** css library. To make it work, you have to remove the html attributes `height="300" width="400"` from your image markup. Your extraordinarily detailled question suggest that this solution should be your desired UI behavior.

So your code might look like this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="border">
            <!-- Remove the fixed width and height and add the class img-fluid -->
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="~/foo/bar.png">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Description:** Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with `.img-fluid` .
> `max-width: 100%; and height: auto;` are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.

Here is the official documentation of bootstrap:

- [4.6.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/images/#responsive-images) (currently used by ASP.NET Core 3.1)
- [5.0.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/#responsive-images) (will be used soon by default)

**PS**: *I strongly encourage you to move every style declaration from your inline-markup to your css to get used to coding best practices. Bootstrap also provides the most important layout and design helpers which should do the basic job (see my answer).*